# How can I use the built-in Python read() function in Julia using PyCall?

Tags: python, io, julia

I'm using Julia, and right now I'm trying to use the PyCall package so that I can use the BeautifulSoup module for web parsing. My Julia code looks something like

```
using PyCall
pyinitialize("python3")
@pyimport bs4 #need BeautifulSoup
@pyimport urllib.request as urllib #need urlopen

url_base = "blah"
html = urllib.urlopen(url_base).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

However, when I try to run it, I get complaints about the `read()` function. I first thought that `read()` would be a built-in Python function, but `pybuiltin("read")` didn't work.

I'm not sure what Python module I can import to get the read function. I  tried importing the `io` module and using `io.read()`, but that didn't work. Additionally, using Julia's built-in read functions didn't work, since `urllib.urlopen(url_base)` is a `PyObject`.

Comment: What Python version are you using? There have been a few changes between Python 2 and 3 with urllib: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: I'm using Python 3 right now. I have urllib.request as the module I'm importing, though I renamed it to urllib since it's easier to type (and I think the "." can't be overloaded in Julia?).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url_base).read()
```

should be

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url_base)[:read]()
```

See the [PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) documentation:

> **Important:** The biggest difference from Python is that object attributes/members are accessed with `o[:attribute]` rather than `o.attribute`, so that `o.method(...)` in Python is replaced by `o[:method](...)` in Julia. Also, you use `get(o, key)` rather than `o[key]`. (However, you can access integer indices via `o[i]` as in Python, albeit with 1-based Julian indices rather than 0-based Python indices.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split out to read the response. Instead of:

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url_base).read()
```

Try:

```
with urllib.urlopen(url_base) as response:
    html = response.read()
```

Python 3 goes a long way improving clarity and readability.

Comment: Ah, sorry if I wasn't clear about this! My comment above probably made it seem like I was coding in Python. I'm using Julia, but I'm using someone's package that lets you import Python modules in Julia. So that syntax doesn't work in Julia.

Comment: Ah, my bad! I was wondering why there was a bizarre syntax, but figured it might be a Julia convention in Python; not the other way around. Apologies for the misunderstanding, and good luck.

Comment: Can you please share the solution. I am also having problems with julia/python syntax. I am trying to execute request = urllib2.Request(url, json_payload, "{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}")